# Alert will not work with vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am following https://laracasts.com/series/learning-vue-step-by-step/episodes/3. I'm working with netbeans 8.1. The alert in the vue object does not occur when I press the submit button, instead the default html action of done.html occurs. The only error in the console is :

```
GET http://localhost:8383/favicon.ico net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

My code is right out of the webcast:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--
    To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
    To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
    and open the template in the editor.
    auth0.com/blog/2015/11/13/build-an-app-with-vuejs/


    -->
    <!--<html>-->
        <head>
            <title>TODO supply a title</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">




        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="app">  
                <form action="done.html">

                    <button type="submit" v-on:submit="handleIt">        
                    <!--<button>-->        
                        submit me!!       
                    </button>





                    <pre> {{$data|json}}</pre>
                </form>



            </div>

            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.12/vue.js"></script>

            <script>

    //            var data = {message: "hi there"}

            new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                methods: {
                        handleIt: function()
                            {alert('hgjfhgjf');}
                    }
                });

            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is the `<html>` commented out?

Comment: ' <!DOCTYPE html>' is at the top

Comment: Okay, so where is `<html>`?

Comment: I thought they were same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not `vuejs` expert, however, as far as I can say, you have to put `v-on:submit` on the form element, like this `<form action="done.html" v-on:submit="handleIt">`

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten that add vue_instance file in the HTML file.